# Group values from array

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have this array:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[id] => Array
    (
        [0] => Koala.jpg
        [1] => Jellyfish.jpg
    )

[desc] => Array
    (
        [0] => koaladesc
        [1] => jelly desc
    )

[qtidade] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 5
    )
```

I need create some php function that help me group the values like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Koala.jpg
        [1] => koaladesc
        [2] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Jellyfish
        [1] => jelly desc
        [2] => 5
    )
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: And... what have you tried?

Comment: yes, this isn't a very specific question. you can use `foreach` to loop through an array - why don't you start there?

Comment: i've tried using foreach but without sucess...

Comment: you should post your attempt, so others can tell you what you're doing wrong and how to fix it. then you would learn something. (this can be done with `foreach`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, but it's localized to what you're asking based on the vagueness of your question:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($simple_xml_object as $obj) {
    if(is_array($obj)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($obj); $i++) {
            $new_array[$i][] = $obj[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest looking at the documentation on the [foreach() construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), as well as looking over the [SimpleXML manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: Thanks faino, i forgot that my input from SimpleXML was an obj not a array, i used your code and  one function to convert obj to array first.
worked well! thanks

Comment: No problem, @user2487040. Glad to be of service. It's also dynamically typed as far and the internal array goes, so instead of just 2 values it could parse 10 no problem. Re-usability in code is very important.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to *tranpose* an array. Here's a magical way of transposing rectangular arrays:

```
array_unshift($array, null);
$array = call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose your array is saved in variable $arrayValues

```
$arrayValues = [id] => Array
(
    [0] => Koala.jpg
    [1] => Jellyfish.jpg
)

[desc] => Array
(
    [0] => koaladesc
    [1] => jelly desc
)

[qtidade] => Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
)
```

now you need to create the following code:

```
foreach($arrayValues as $array)
{
    echo $array->id;
    echo $array->desc;
    echo $array->qtidade;
}
```

this may work well for you.